# Update column in a different server, based on ID - SQL Server 2008R2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have Server 1 and Server2. The column that should be updated is on Server 1, the data that will update information is on Server 2 - same table, same column and names.

Comment: Try to use `SqlConnection` of `Server 1` to retrieve data and for `UPDATE` use `SqlConnection` of `Server 2`.

Comment: Read about linked servers - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560998.aspx

Comment: How can I do this using sqlconnection?
Lets say server1 ip is 192.168.0.1
and server2 ip is 192.168.0.2

I want to run something like this:

 UPDATE tableA
   SET tableA.colB=tableB.colB
   FROM tableB
   WHERE tableA.colA=tableA.colA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options available but it's really very dependent on you requirements.

If you just want to manually sync the tables you could use a tool like Redagates [SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/)

If you want to sync the tables based on a schedule you could set up a [Linked Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560998.aspx) with a simple update.. UPDATE Table SET Column = (SELECT Column FROM Server2.Database2.Table)

Or you could [replicate the objects](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Or you could implement the sync in the data layer of your application

---

From your comment it looks like you want to set up linked servers but be aware of the  [performance issues](http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/b/weblog/archive/2013/05/14/top-3-performance-killers-for-linked-server-queries.aspx) you can encounter.

Comment: Gary, I messed up a column on a table which had agreement status(accepted, rejected, etc) on the production server.
I already restored the database on another server, what I need now is just match the agreements IDs and set their status back to the original state, there is about 890k agreements that will need to be fixed.
What do you believe to be the best option to do this?

Answer (score 0):

implement Transactional replication between two servers. Set server 1 as publisher and server 2 as subscriber. Use article filter in order to permit just update would be available.

Comment: I want to run something like this:
 UPDATE tableA
   SET tableA.colB=tableB.colB
   FROM tableB
   WHERE tableA.colA=tableA.colA
    
Table A will be on server 1 and table B being on server 2, both on same wlan.

I never heard of Transnational replication, can you give me a example on how this works?

Comment: Ok, Look when we want to make multiple databases on multiple servers synchronized it is good to use replication.any way if you want to query on both servers use linked server. on Sql server management studio on top on view node click registered servers and there you can register another server and can open a new query window on both server linked. but also you can use linked server in other way which can read in here :  msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560998.aspx .

Comment: Fixed my previous comment.